# 404/410 responses. Either fix the broken links or remove the references to non-existent

Tags: magento2.3, performance, optimization, speedoptimization, gtmetrix

following errors are returned when our site is tested on gtmetrix. Could you please share your insights into how to resolve them?

[image]

Comment: When this sort of error comes up, please try clearing your page cache plugin as it’s possible old pages are still referencing it.

Comment: @Mohit Patel, okay, but this had something to do with the incorrect .htaccess file I copy pasted into pub/static folder improperly. Fixed this by pasting the appropriate one into the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question since it wasn't answered till now when I have fixed it by ensuring that the .htaccess file in the pub/static folder wasn't the right one and downloading a copy of the right one. One can download the appropriate one from the github and put in this folder.